# Repeat a rowspan cell on each spanned page?

Tags: html, css, printing, flying-saucer

I am using [flying saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) to print an HTML table where cells in first column can span a large number of rows (to multiple pages). The requriement is for the cell to repeat on each page it spans (like a `<thead>`).

The library supports CSS2.1 and some CSS3 (e.g. the [Paged Media Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/)), but no JavaScript. And as far as I can see, there's nothing in the standards that can directly do this.

Is there any hack or something that can make this possible?

(I control the code that generates the HTML, but the number of rows on a page cannot be predicted.)